# Geocode without parse?

Tags: geocoding

Scheduled job: geocoding=1 parse=0 start=1 end=nnnn throttle=1 results in a fail.
Failure, Error message: Error: You need to enable Street Address Parsing under Administer > Localization > Address Settings.
In Civi 5.27.7 ESP (WP 5.6.1) the only way to do this is to enter a standardisation provider - only USPS offered and account required.
Is there any way to force geocoding without configuring a provider? I don't need or request the parse.
(This used to work out of the box. Earlier contacts in the db have a map)

BPCG

Comment: Which geocoding provider are you using? Does it work without start/end params? I use this configuration without trouble myself.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, I've now got this working by creating a new api credential. BPCG